# Are closed questions degraded in SEO or recommended?

Tags: discussion

The question - [GoLang buffer sizing during Unmarshall for Base64 too large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887063/golang-buffer-sizing-during-unmarshall-for-base64-too-large)

Obviously the close reason is correct - but for only half the question (yes I realize I had two questions in one).

But when I was searching for the other half of the question (how costly .DecodedLen is, and why the difference in base64 Len), I didn’t see any good answers. I got valuable answers in the comments. It’d be a bummer if that wasn’t available to the next person.

Comment: So why not rewrite the question? Please note that "UPDATE"s are very confusing. I read the question for the first time in the form that it's currently presented, so I don't understand why you have such clause at the end.

Comment: oh, because i didn't want to hide the context of the original comments. To be clear, i think the reason for close is correct, but I wanted to make sure it was still valuable for future searchers.

Comment: Edits are supposed to invalidate comments. The whole purpose of comments is to ask for clarifications to the question. The proper reply to comments is editing the post. Once you address the comments through the edit, you can flag comments as no longer needed

Comment: Interesting! Will do for the future i guess - since this one is closed.

Still would be a bummer if this got excluded from SEO/search tool because it's closed.

Comment: But why give up on this question? Closed just means that it's pending further edits from its author.

Comment: I don't have any insight about SEO, but I do find many closed questions with answers on Google search result. The problem is that comments are not answers, and this question will be [roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: You could also write a new question about the other half of the question. Feel free to turn the comments into answers (giving proper attribution, of course).

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to do this. It was annoying for me to understand it, would like to give back